# python, inserting in to 2d list

Tags: python

I am trying to insert "X" to specific place in list. it seems to place "X" in every list. There is parts of "def umieszczanie_statkow_na_tablicy_komputera" that are useless so don't look at it.

```py
import random as r

liczba_statkow = 5
wielkosc_tablicy_x = 9
wielkosc_tablicy_y = 9

def tworzenie_tablicy(wielkosc_tablicy_x, wielkosc_tablicy_y):
    global stworzona_tablica
    a = "*"
    b = ["*"]
    for i in range(wielkosc_tablicy_x-1):
        b.append(a)
    stworzona_tablica = []
    for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_y):
        stworzona_tablica.append(b)

    for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_y):
        print(stworzona_tablica[_])

tworzenie_tablicy(wielkosc_tablicy_x, wielkosc_tablicy_y)
tablica_gracza = stworzona_tablica
tablica_komputera = stworzona_tablica

def umieszczanie_statkow_na_tablicy_komputera(tablica_komputera, liczba_statkow, wielkosc_tablicy_x, wielkosc_tablicy_y):
    print(" ")
    liczba_statkow = 5
    #for i in range(liczba_statkow):
    wspozedna_x = r.randint(0, wielkosc_tablicy_x-1)
    wspozedna_y = r.randint(0, wielkosc_tablicy_y-1)

    del tablica_komputera[5][5]
    tablica_komputera[5].insert(5, "X")
    
    for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_y):
        print(tablica_komputera[_])
umieszczanie_statkow_na_tablicy_komputera(
    tablica_komputera, liczba_statkow, wielkosc_tablicy_x, wielkosc_tablicy_y)
```

[image: .]

Comment: Add your code to question

Comment: Code in text not as image

Comment: If i don't del  result is the same

Comment: See my answer, you don't need del + insert, just set the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep appending the same exact `b` list, the same instance, so when you modifying one, you see it everywhere, you need to copy it

```
stworzona_tablica.append(b)        # NOK
stworzona_tablica.append(list(b))  # OK
```

---

Also, better practices to

- don't use global variable, return value
- I'm pretty sure `tablica_gracza` `tablica_komputera` don't need to be names pointing to the same list, but they may need to be copies
- `del` + `insert` is useless, just set a new value

```
def tworzenie_tablicy(wielkosc_tablicy_x, wielkosc_tablicy_y):
    a = "*"
    stworzona_tablica = [[a for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_x)]
                         for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_y)]
    return stworzona_tablica

tablica_gracza = tworzenie_tablicy(wielkosc_tablicy_x, wielkosc_tablicy_y)
tablica_komputera = deepcopy(tablica_gracza)

def umieszczanie_statkow_na_tablicy_komputera(tablica_komputera, liczba_statkow, wielkosc_tablicy_x,
                                              wielkosc_tablicy_y):
    tablica_komputera[5][5] = "X"

    for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_y):
        print(tablica_komputera[_])
```

Comment: Ok, i get it Thank You and sorry - I didn't think creating a list this way will affect it

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it is essentially doing this:

```
x = ["*"] * 9
y = [x for _ in range(9)]
print(y)
y[5][5] = "X"
print(y)
```

The issue with this is that your lists identically the same as each other (i.e. `y[0] is y[1]`), not just equal. This means that when you change one of them, the others are automatically changed as well.

To fix this, you need there to be nine different list objects. The easiest way to do this is this.

```py
y = [["*"] * 9 for _ in range(9)]
```

In your case, you can just change

```py
for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_y):
    stworzona_tablica.append(b)
```

to

```py
for _ in range(wielkosc_tablicy_y):
    stworzona_tablica.append(b.copy())
```

in order to tell Python that you want to add many copies of a list, not the exact same list itself multiple times.